# react-hook-form onsubmit data showing old defaultvalues, (although watch prints updated value)

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, react-hook-form

React-hook-form issue:
I have a table which is responsive, but the layout is different so I have 2 different component for this.

This is a table, where the user can edit it's content.
Here is the layout:
[image]

When the user clicks on the green button, the editing will be done, and the values will be saved. It's a bit tricky, because the the button trigger the react-hook-form onSubmit which is in a different component solved with forwardRef.

```
("react-hook-form": "^7.38.0",)
```

Here is the EditableView code:

```
import React, { forwardRef } from "react";
import { useForm, useFieldArray } from "react-hook-form";
import { useProfileContext } from "../../context/ProfileContext";
import PrimaryButton from "../Button/PrimaryButton";

const EditableDayMenu = forwardRef(({ weekOfYear, dayOfWeek, menu }, ref) => {
  const { register, control, handleSubmit, watch, getValues } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      menu: menu?.map((item) => {
        return {
          menuCategory: item.menuCategory,
          menuDescription: item.menuDescription,
        };
      }),
    },
  });

  const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: "menu",
  });
  const { handleMenu } = useProfileContext();

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(Data);
    handleMenu(weekOfYear, dayOfWeek, data);
  };

  console.log(watch());

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      {fields.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div className="" key={item.id}>
            <label className="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">
              Menü kategória
            </label>
            <input
              className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
              {...register(`menu.${index}.menuCategory`, { required: true })}
            />
            <label className="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">
              Menü leírása
            </label>
            <textarea
              rows={5}
              className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
              {...register(`menu.${index}.menuDescription`, { required: true })}
            />

            <button
              className="mb-3"
              type="button"
              onClick={() => remove(index)}
            >
              Menü törlése
            </button>
          </div>
        );
      })}
      <button
        className="block lg:hidden xl:block mx-auto"
        type="button"
        onClick={() => {
          append({ menuCategory: "", menuDescription: "" });
        }}
      >
        <PrimaryButton text={"Új menü hozzáadása"} />
      </button>
      <button
        className="hidden lg:block xl:hidden mx-auto"
        type="button"
        onClick={() => {
          append({ menuCategory: "", menuDescription: "" });
        }}
      >
        <PrimaryButton text={"+"} />
      </button>
      <button hidden={true} ref={ref} type={"submit"} />
    </form>
  );
});

export default EditableDayMenu;
EditableDayMenu.displayName = "EditableDayMenu";
```

The whole menu with the refs:

```
const WeeklyMenu = ({ allMenu, isEditable = true }) => {
  const [currentWeek, setCurrentWeek] = useState();
  const [isEditView, setIsEditView] = useState(false);
  const fixWeek = Number(moment().format("w"));
  const arrLength = 7;
  const elRefs = React.useRef([]);
  const mobileelRefs = React.useRef([]);
  const [isMobileView, setIsMobileView] = useState();
  
  const handleResize = () => {
     window.innerWidth>1024 ? setIsMobileView(false) : 
     setIsMobileView(true)
  }



  if (elRefs.current.length !== arrLength) {
    // add or remove refs
    elRefs.current = Array(arrLength)
      .fill()
      .map((_, i) => elRefs.current?.[i] || createRef());
  }
  
  if (mobileelRefs.current.length !== arrLength) {
    // add or remove refs
    mobileelRefs.current = Array(arrLength)
      .fill()
      .map((_, i) => mobileelRefs.current?.[i] || createRef());
  }

 
  const menuThisWeek = menuOfTheWeek(currentWeek);


  return (
    <div className="text-Brand-Primary relative pt-4 lg:pt-0">
      {menuThisWeek != null && isEditable && (
        <div className="flex items-center gap-x-2 absolute right-0 w-full justify-center sm:w-fit">
          
          {!isEditView ? (
            <button
              onClick={() => setIsEditView(true)}
              className="bg-Brand-Secondary rounded-2xl px-3 py-2 text-white hover:bg-opacity-80"
            >
              Menü szerkesztése
            </button>
          ) : (
            <button
              onClick={() => {
                setIsEditView(false);
                const weekResponsiveButtons = isMobileView ? mobileelRefs : elRefs
                console.log(isMobileView)
                weekResponsiveButtons.current.forEach((ref) => {
                  console.log(ref.current);
                  ref.current?.click();
                });
              }}
              className="bg-green-500 rounded-2xl px-3 py-2 text-white hover:bg-opacity-80"
            >
              Mentés
            </button>
          )}
        </div>
      )}
      <div className="block lg:hidden h-12" />
      <p className="text-3xl">Heti menü</p>
     
      <div className="w-full space-x-3 hidden lg:flex">
      <DesktopWeeklyMenu
          isEditView={isEditView}
          weeks={getCurrentWeek(fixWeek - currentWeek)}
          menus={menuThisWeek}
          currentWeek={currentWeek}
          elRefs={elRefs}
          menuThisWeek={menuThisWeek}
        />
      </div>
      {(
        <MobileWeeklyMenu
          isEditView={isEditView}
          weeks={getCurrentWeek(fixWeek - currentWeek)}
          menus={menuThisWeek}
          currentWeek={currentWeek}
          elRefs={mobileelRefs}
          menuThisWeek={menuThisWeek}
        />
      )}

      {menuThisWeek == null && (
        <UnlockMenuWeek weekOfYear={currentWeek} isEditable={isEditable} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default WeeklyMenu;
```

When I try to edit in the desktop layout, it works perfectly, in the mobile layout it's not, although we are using the same EditableDayMenu component in both:

```
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    handleMenu(weekOfYear, dayOfWeek, data)
};
    
    console.log(watch())
```

When we try to submit the form, the data only shows the old (defaultValues), but the console.log(watch()) prints out the latest updated fields, so I don't understand why it is not the same in the onsubmit (and what is the difference between my desktop and mobile approach?)

Desktop layout:

```
import React from 'react'
import EditableDayMenu from './EditableDayMenu';

const DesktopWeeklyMenu = ({
    isEditView,
    weeks,
    menus,
    currentWeek,
    elRefs,
    menuThisWeek,
}) => {
  return (
    <table className="table-fixed w-[90%] mx-auto border-2 border-gray-500 rounded-xl">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        {weeks.map((item) => {
          return (
            <th
              key={item}
              className="border border-gray-400 text-Brand-Secondary px-1 xl:px-6"
            >
              {item}
            </th>
          );
        })}
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        {menuThisWeek?.map((day, dayOfWeek) => {
          return (
            <td
              key={day + dayOfWeek}
              valign="top"
              className="border border-gray-400 p-1 2xl:p-3"
            >
              <div className="flex flex-col gap-y-3">
                {!isEditView &&
                  day.day?.map((menu, idx) => {
                    return (
                      <div key={menu.menuCategory + idx}>
                        <p className="font-bold text-lg">
                          {menu.menuCategory}
                        </p>
                        <p className="font-base text-gray-700 break-all">
                          {menu.menuDescription}
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    );
                  })}
              </div>
              {isEditView && (
                <EditableDayMenu
                  ref={elRefs.current[dayOfWeek]}
                  weekOfYear={currentWeek}
                  dayOfWeek={dayOfWeek}
                  menu={day.day}
                />
                
              )}
            </td>
          );
        })}
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
    )
}

export default DesktopWeeklyMenu
```

Mobile layout:

```
import React from "react";
import EditableDayMenu from "./EditableDayMenu";
import UnlockMenuWeek from "./UnlockMenuWeek";

const MobileWeeklyMenu = ({
  isEditView,
  weeks,
  menus,
  currentWeek,
  elRefs,
  menuThisWeek,
}) => {

  return (
    <table className="w-full mx-auto border-collapse border-spacing-10 block lg:hidden whitespace-normal border-2 border-gray-500 rounded-xl overflow-x-auto">
      {weeks.map((week, dayOfWeek) => {
        return (
          <tr key={week}>
            <th className="border w-[30%] border-gray-400 text-Brand-Secondary px-1 xl:px-6">
              {week}
            </th>
            <td valign="top" className={`border border-gray-400 p-3 ${menuThisWeek==null ? 'bg-slate-200' :''}`}>
              {menus?.[dayOfWeek]?.day?.map((day, index) => {
                return !isEditView ? (
                  <div key={day.menuCategory + index}>
                    <p className="font-bold text-lg">{day.menuCategory}</p>
                    <p className="font-base text-gray-700 break-all">
                      {day.menuDescription}
                    </p>
                  </div>
                ) : (
                  <EditableDayMenu
                    key={day.menuCategory + index+"edit"}
                    ref={elRefs.current[dayOfWeek]}
                    weekOfYear={currentWeek}
                    dayOfWeek={dayOfWeek}
                    menu={menus?.[dayOfWeek]?.day}
                  />
                );
              })}
            </td>
          </tr>
        );
      })}
     
    </table>
  );
};

export default MobileWeeklyMenu;
```

Here is an example of the log in the mobile layout:
[image]
`Watch`:

```
{menu: Array(3)}menu: Array(3)0: {menuCategory: 'EDIT CATEGORY NAME', menuDescription: 'Leves minden leírva blabla, második'}1: ...
```

OnSubmit:

```
 {menu: Array(3)}menu: Array(3)0: {menuCategory: 'a1', menuDescription: 'Leves minden leírva blabla, második'}1: ...
```

After save:
[image]

You can see, that the edited value will not be stored, it's very strange, because the same works in the desktop version, hope you guys can help me figure it out.